# Adding Google Maps Marker in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to add a marker created by a user to `localStorage`? I would like the retrieve the same coordinates of the marker that was added by the user if the browser refreshes or closes. It seems like `localStorage` can help achieve that.

I am trying something as follows, which doesn't seem correct. Please note that I am fairly new to JavaScript.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
        localStorage.setItem('marker',true);
        localStorage.getItem('marker');
});
```

I think it may be setting the marker in `localStorage`, but I can't see it upon page refresh.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to store the marker itself you will get an error "Converting circular structure to JSON", even after stringifying it. Plus, it will store extra data which you may not need. I recommend you to store in the browser as minimum as possible of data due to space limitations.

What you can do instead is create your datatype to holds the info of marker (lat and long) and store this object. See the following....

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.123456789, -36.123456789); 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng
            });
var newMarker = {Lat: marker.position.lat(), Lng: marker.position.lng()};
localStorage["marker1"] = JSON.stringify(newMarker);
console.log(localStorage["marker1"]);
```

play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/94qhJ/

Comment: I've been trying this since yesterday, but need some guidance (see: http://jsfiddle.net/ZT2Un/1/). `localStorage` doesn't seem to work in jsFiddle due to security reasons I guess (see console for errors). In my own server, I get an error that `storeMarker` is not defined. I'm not sure how to make it a global variable. I tried to merge the code provided by you and Google. Trying to store the markers in `localStorage` as they are added on the map through clicks.

Comment: i have made some changes. please try it out
http://jsfiddle.net/G9d2P/

localStorage is working for me. Can you try different browser?

Comment: Thanks alsafoo. It seems to be working now as I can see in console log. But is it possible to retrieve these markers once they are "set" into `localStorage`? I was looking at adding `var loadMarkers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('markerTest'));` and `loadMarkers.setMap(map)`, but I'm not sure where to place them. I hope I have the right idea.

Comment: You got it right, do this to get all markers from localstorage.

`var loadMarkers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('markerTest'));`

Get the lat and lng, then create new markers with these positions.

Comment: I keep getting an error that object (i.e., loadMarkers) has no method `setMap`. I am placing this after `localStorage` is set.

Comment: what we stored in localstorage are just lat and lng of the markers, not the google map marker. so what you need to do is create a google map marker same way you were doing it and assign the lat and lng that we have to 'position'

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. See lines 38-43 (http://jsfiddle.net/N5Cfg). What I'm unsure of is whether to add this in the `initialize` function or somewhere else? Placing it outside of `addMarker` will lead to global/local variable problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: if you use jquery, put all your initialization in `$(document).ready` function. then create a new javascript module, the same as `loader` module you have now, and call it for instance googlMapModule, this module will deal only with the map, and you can have a marker module to deal only with markers. you can join the two modules instead if you don't have a lot of code.